# Making and receiving payments?

Tags: .net, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, payment-gateway, payment

I am looking at building a Website that needs to receive payments from clients and make payments to service providers.  Payments will most likely come in as Credit Card purchases and then monthly I will most likely have to pay the service providers after taking a fee.   I know there are a lot of options for accepting money via a payment gateway but I also would like to make payments to the bank accounts of the service providers as there could be a 1000+ service providers and I don't want to have to cut all those checks or have to manually send them the money.   What options do I have for automating the payment of service providers which will mostly be individuals and not companies.

Comment: This realy depends on where your business is located and where the service providers are located.

Comment: The business is US based as well as the service providers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're based in the USA then you're going to want to look at [ACH](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automated_Clearing_House) APIs for doing this. Generally these will charge a per-payment fee rather than a % based fee like you'd be charged for doing credit card processing.

Here's a quick list of ACH processors I found via a quick Google for [ACH API](https://google.com/?q=ACH+API)

- BancBox - http://www.bancbox.com/
- ACH Works - http://www.achworks.com/
- Balanced - https://www.balancedpayments.com/
- FirstACH - http://www.firstach.com/
- ACH Direct - http://www.achdirect.com/

Comment: Out of those options I'd choose Balanced as their business model is directly for marketplace websites with payments in and payments out. The others focus on ACH transfers and moving money around, which is a slightly different proposition.

Comment: Quick update on a thread above: "Here's a quick list of ACH processors I found via a quick Google for ACH API" ACH Direct has actually rebranded and is now known as Forte Payment Systems - http://www.forte.net/

Answer (score 0):

In this case you're looking at two, whilst similar, completely distinct operations.

as Far as accepting payments your options are credit card (via a gateway like authorize.net), payment providers (pay pal, amazon, etc.) or manually charged via a terminal and of course cash & checks.

to pay your providers its all about what they offer as methods. It might be manual (checks), web based payments or there might be an api they offer.